# Capacitive discharge excess being used for battery recharging

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, lithium-ion, high-voltage, efficiency

I am currently designing a circuit similar to a cattle prod that is intended to be attached to a drone. The cattle prod is powered by a lithium-ion battery, charging up a capacitor and then quickly discharging through a material. It will be delivering approximately 1 J of energy with a 10 kV voltage, at about 7 kHz. I am trying to make the system more efficient.

I know next to nothing about power electronics or batteries (I am studying computer science), and was wondering if it is possible to use any residual current from the discharge to cycle back through and recharge the battery without any mechanical components? If not, can you please explain why? I am currently looking at the MAX8900 IC, and if it is possible I would like to know what I would have to do to process the current so it could be the input to such an IC.

Comment: Placing a [cattle prod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle_prod), also known as a shock prod, onto a drone... Why would you possibly want to do this? Shock your friends? Shock birds?

Comment: Since a capacitor would be used for the discharges, you will *by default* recover the leftover energy: if e.g. 5 kV remains in the cap after each discharge, when recharging it for the next pulse you'll only have to recharge it from *5 kV to 10 kV*. You do realize that 1 J discharges at 7 kHz require 7 kW of power, which is impractical for a "drone" (assuming a 1 kg quadcopter)?

Comment: @HarrySvensson it is a forestry project haha, I'm not that sadistic! Although now I am getting ideas...

Comment: @jms thanks! As for the second part of your comment, are you able to explain? Is it not dependent on the time constant of my circuit?

Comment: Are you trying to get free energy? Whatever energy that you put "back" will *not* used on whatever is supposed to get shocked. Example: 1J is delivered to a cow.  You will have to subtract from your 1J to put it elsewhere, such as in the battery. So perhaps 0.8J goes to the cow. But that would serve no purpose, as you could have just supplied 0.8J to begin with, instead of trying to take energy from the battery and put it right back in to the battery. So perhaps I am misunderstanding.

Comment: You may have some leeway depending on where you live, but be aware that it is possible that what you intend to build is very illegal.  Aside from that, a great deal of skill is necessary to deliver a "safe" shock of any consequence.  Also I'm pretty sure that as jms indicates 7000 1 joule pulses per second will not particularly resemble safe.

Comment: @Bort jms answered above

Comment: @KH it is not intended for human use, but rather is industrial, as I mentioned above it is for a forestry project, not for use on any animal or human. It is designed with industrial safety regulations. 
As for what jms said, it will not be delivered at 7000 pulses per second, rather the capacitor circuit has a frequency of 7kHz.
Regardless, this was not a post asking about the safety considerations, but the battery.

Comment: eles, jms is talking specifically about the capacitor *possibly* retaining a slight charge after a shock. But you had asked about the "residual current from the discharge". Since you mentioned current, I imagined that you were talking about capturing the current *while it's shocking something*.

Comment: It may be wise to clarify the statement "similar to a cattle prod" (a device whose significant property is to deliver "safe" electrical shocks.) and change the phrase "1 J of energy with a 10 kV voltage, at about 7 kHz" to "1 J pulses at 10 kV.  The 10kV will be stored in a capacitor powered by a *type_of_voltage_boost_circuit* operating at 7 kHz.".